# building a private cloud

Tags: hp, hp-procurve

I’m building a private cloud for my company and want to get the right advise for network setup.

This setup is only for infrastructure and not for client access.
I use: 3 X ESX hosts, 2 HP 1920 48G switches, Storage iSCSI and NFS, 1 firewall with Wan, DMZ, Lan interface.

What would be the best way to connect the switches for HA ? setup Stuck ?  or Trunk with 2 ports ? on that trunk to set LACP ?

The storage has 4 interfaces for iSCSI and 4 for NFS, NFS set as LACP on the storage end – how should I connect cables from the storage to the switches ? in cross or from each controller one cable to each switch with LACP enabled ?
What are my options for HA with the firewalls Lan interface (network Default gateway) how can it be connected to both switches ?

Comment: It might be better for you to show us your design and then we can suggest improvements.   Asking for a network design involves a lot more detailed information than you've provided.  Not to mention, many professionals on this site earn their living designing networks for others.  You can't expect them to do it for free here.

Comment: Mike, you need 10G connectivity.  Don't deploy both switches in a stack fashion.  They should be completely independent.  You should not have a single firewall - no single point of failure.  Good luck.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The HP 1920 switches aren't really enterprise level switches and definately do not support 10Gb connectivity. So if you are connecting your hosts to the ISCSI storage where your guests are located, 1Gb/s, even if aggregated, wouldn't give you great performance.

The 1920's are more aimed for small office environment. Ideally what you would want to do is use switches that can do real stacking and be seen as a single switch for higher availability and then alternate the ports between them with LACP trunks. There is a lot to your question and I agree with Ron. We can only help and suggest improvements. The research and the real work will need to be done by yourself.

Send us information on how you are planning to connect everything. Start with what you know and then we can go from there.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleeoyMan

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific need for NFS, why bother?  I don't see much NFS in corporate environments myself.  What I do see is iSCSI presentation of LUNs to ESX hosts.  Use four dedicated iSCSI VLANs with one cable from the storage to each, two per switch.  Do the same for each ESX host.  Then use iSCSI multipath to increase bandwidth beyond 1Gbps.  I haven't connected to four iSCSI paths myself but I assume it's possible.  The iSCSI VLANs don't even appear on the switch interlinks.